# Travel visa for a US immigrant

Tags: visas, usa, japan, filipino-citizens

I'm a Philippines citizen. I'm a green card holder, residing in Los Angeles, California. I want to visit Japan just to experience and see their tradition.

How can I have a visit visa and what are the requirements?

Answer (score 3):

As a Philippines citizen, you will need a visa to visit Japan (this is true whether or not you are a US resident). You can find all the visa information you'll need from [the Japanese Consulate in Los Angeles](http://www.la.us.emb-japan.go.jp/e_web/visa_how_to_apply.htm), particularly [the page on short-term visas](http://www.la.us.emb-japan.go.jp/e_web/e_m02_06_04.htm).

For tourism/sightseeing visas, there's [a list of required documents](http://www.la.us.emb-japan.go.jp/pdf/SIGHTSEEING_TOURISM.pdf) for a visa. Complete all that, and take it to the consulate for a visa.

If you do obtain US citizenship in the future, you'll be able to visit Japan for up to 90 days for tourism or business visa-free.